# textinput restrict to accept number with four decimal precision

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex3

I have a textfield in which I want to restrict user to enter only valid number with 14 digit before .(dot) and 4 digit after .(dot).

I have tried it using :

```
<mx:TextInput id="txtValue1" restrict="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]" maxChars="19"/>
```

Its not working for restriction 4 digit after .(dot).

Answer (score 0):

A more common way would be to use a NumberValidator, and set the precision attribute of the validator to 4. Also, set the maxValue of the NumberValidator to whatever suits, then set the source of the NumberValidator to the textInput id. That should work I'd say, and it will also allow you to set the error fields of the validator which will pop up beside the textInput if incorrect number is entered

Comment: I am not able to define textInput "id" attribute as its a root element.

Comment: yeah paste the code from temp file, but anyways I have added HBox as a parent component and going with the NumberValidator way only.Thanks!!

Comment: can we achieve this using restrict only ?

Comment: You can listen to textInput.change event, and apply a RegExp to allow characters as discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pune-flex-users/ParAxoTgsxY, but I think the NumberValidator is much clearer, more maintainable, and less prone to bugs

Answer (score 0):

you can view and download a code (this works!) in my public repository from this [LINK](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/tree/master/NumberInput).
Basically, i created a class (NumberInput) based on TextInput class from Adobe, the diferrence in both classes was the textFieldChanged method, i add a call here to myFormat function(). This function does what you're needing. 
Be careful with this class, do not use it as the final solution but I will anyway to find what you need. Check the SWF called NumberInputTest.swf, source code is in src\NumberInput.as. 
I hope this help you. Sorry for my english :D.